# nginx + php-fpm using socket says 404 file not found

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, http-status-code-404, fpm

I have configured my server with nGinx that accesses PHP via FastCGI.
It works fine when I use a port.  As soon as I change to a socket and restart the servers, it says "404 Not Found".

The reason I chose this setup was for developing reasons, to have multiple versions of PHP to test my code with.  (And using ports, I can have different IP addresses having different PHP versions.)

(Because there's so many files involved, I am only putting the main ones here.  If more files are required to view, please ask.)

**php-fpm.conf:**

```
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        4;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections      1024;
}
http {
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log       main;

        sendfile                on;
        tcp_nopush              on;
        tcp_nodelay             on;
        keepalive_timeout       2;
        types_hash_max_size     2048;

        include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type    application/octet-stream;

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

**sites-enabled/socket-php55:**

```
server {
                listen          80;
                listen          [::]:80;
                server_name     192.168.1.55    php55   php55.ultra.centos;
                        root            /var/www/html;
                        index   index.php;

                location / {
                }
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files       $uri    $uri/   /index.php      =404;
                        fastcgi_index   index.php;
                        include         fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9055;
#                        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5.5-fpm.socket;
                }
                location ~ /\.ht {
                        deny    all;
                }
                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
                }
        }
```

**php-fpm.d/www.conf:**

```
...
listen = 9055
#listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php5.5-fpm.socket
...
```

The above works, however if I remove the comments (and also comment the above line), to use a socket, it fails.
Please explain why this won't serve a (eg. phpinfo) page when using a socket.

Comment: What user is `php-fpm` running as? Does `nginx` have read/write permissions on the created socket?

Comment: Good thinking!
I've changed my php-fpm pool file to user nobody & group nobody.  Then I deleted the old socket file.  As soon as I restart the service it re-creates the socket: "srw-rw----.  1 root   root      0  php5.5-fpm.socket".
So what user/group should I use?